# How big is the PC demo?

Tags: pc, mass-effect-3

I'm nearly done building a desktop, but currently don't have my "data" hard drives, just small SSDs for Windows and a few programs.  I've been holding off installing any games since I have little space left, but I kinda want to try the ME3 demo and see what all the fuss is about.

However, I can't find any info on how big the demo is.  The Origin website and the in-app page for the demo don't seem to have the size and I didn't see anything with a search.  How big is it?  (Preferably when installed, but the size of the download would be useful also.)  The full game appears to be [10 GB](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3), which would be too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The demo will take up to 2.5 GB of hard drive space on the PC.

Source: [Official Mass Effect 3 Demo FAQ](https://help.ea.com/uk/article/mass-effect-3-demo-faq)

Comment: Ha.  I'll have to append "FAQ" to my searches ;) thanks!

Comment: No problem! Hopefully you'll find 2.5 GB so you can give the game a try. :)

Comment: Lol actually searching "mass effect 3 demo faq" gives the same link but without `uk/` in the URL, which leads to an error page.  EA's websites really suck.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some info now that I've had the experience of getting the demo:

- Origin says it's 2.115 GB before it starts downloading.
- After the install it says it was 2.5 GB.
- **On disk it's actually 2.07 GB**.

Answer (score -1):

Are you asking about the size in GB? Or how long it is? I can tell you both. The Demo contains two levels of the full game, and is 2.5GB in size. Both levels are near the very beginning of the game, so it isn't spoiling much. I think it took me about an hour and a half, perhaps a bit less, to complete both levels.